# how to setup the path of error document on subdomain

Tags: php, .htaccess

i am having problem in displaying my page for 404 error the blog is

original domain http://www.original.com

subdomain http://subdom.original.com

i have uploaded all the data inside the public_html/subdom folder the web site is functioning fine.

below is the entry in my .htaccess file

```
ErrorDocument 404 /public_html/subdom/errors/notfound.html
```

the directory errors and the file inside does exist there so there is problem with setting up the path to it.

can some one help me figure out the path where to start ? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just giving the wrong path. The path for `ErrorDocument` should be relative to your website root. If this url/file `http://subdom.original.com/index.php` is located at `public_html/subdom/index.php` then you need to change your directive to the one below:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /errors/notfound.html
```

If still nothing -- try adding `/subdom` in front:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /subdom/errors/notfound.html
```